# ormlite store unknown foreign object in DatabaseField

Tags: java, android, database, generics, ormlite

For example :

i need an **Animals** table which will contain animal_type as **Object** or **T** type as foreign relation field.

then i will have 10 different tables like Dog/Cat/Horse etc.

at the time of insertion based on type of animal i would set animal_type of Animal object.

I don't want to take multiple databaseField for each type as a foreign relation, instead i need one generic field , Using ormlite version **5.0**.

please refer this json:`{
  "animal": {
    "type": 1,
    "content": {
      "items": [
        {
          "title": "Image",
          "desc": "This is item with image",
          "media": {
            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Earth_rise_from_the_Moon_AS11-44-6550_2.JPG",
            "type": 0
          },
          "options": [
            {
              "title": "View",
              "value": "view"
            },
            {
              "title": "Download",
              "value": "download"
            }
          ],
          "url": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AEarth_rise_from_the_Moon_AS11-44-6550_2.JPG"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`

Comment: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/SerializableType.html

tried this type but no luck.